# Web2Py error: invalid function blog/thanks

Tags: python, web2py, debian-based

I am building a simple blog using Web2Py on Debian Linux. 
I have a controller called blog.py, to which I added the following function, along with an if block:

```
def display_form():
    form = SQLFORM(db.blog)
    if form.process().accepted:
        session.flash = 'form accepted'
        redirect(URL('thanks'))
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash = 'form has errors'
    else:
        response.flash = 'please fill out the form'
    return locals()
```

I proceeded to add a "view" html file called **blog/display_form.html**, with a basic template, as follows:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h1>Display Form</h1>
{{=form}}
```

I load the **"display_form"** blog page just fine, and it accepts all the input successfully, but it does not redirect to a *thank you* page. Instead, the browser generates an *"invalid function blog/thanks"* error.

I tried removing the compiled app via the Web2Py admin interface, and recompiled everything. Still does not work. I added a "view" for the "Thanks" page, but that does not change anything. I restarted the Web2Py framework and the web server, but still no go. 
Some web sites refer to a possible routes.py issue, but I am confused as to why that would be pertinent at all.

Please help, 
I am hitting a brick wall here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass only a single argument to the `URL()` helper, it assumes that argument is the function name and that the controller is the current controller. Since the current controller is `blog`, `URL('thanks')` will generate the following URL: `/yourapp/blog/thanks`.

Presumably, your `thanks` function is in a different controller (perhaps `default.py`), in which case, a request for the above URL will generate the error you observe. Just change the URL to `URL('default', 'thanks')`.

Comment: thanks for your response. I do not have a **thanks** function in any of the controllers. **default.py** doesn't have it. Do I need to define it? If so, any idea how to go about doing that? Thanks again.

Comment: I think I read somewhere that **blog.py** controller is supposed to contain the **thanks** function. **blog.py** currently only contains **display_form**, **index**, **post**, and **view** functions. I also defined the _tables_ **blog** inside **db.py**, but I am not sure how to define the **thanks** function.

Comment: Is it something like: `def redirectme():
    redirect(URL('Thanks'))`, or do I need other arguments?

Comment: If you want to redirect to a "thank you" page, of course you must actually create such a page. The way to do that in web2py is to create a function in a controller and an associated view. I don't know why you would expect your blog.py controller to contain a `thanks` function if you haven't actually created such a function -- after all, you are the one who created the blog.py controller.

Comment: It is because I am a complete *noob* as far as Python is concerned (or any type of coding for that matter). And I only started using Web2Py yesterday. Hence the cry for help. ;) I accepted your answer as the correct one anyhow. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, it was just confusing because you said, "I read somewhere that blog.py controller is supposed to contain the thanks function". It was unclear what that meant if you were the creator of the blog.py controller.

Comment: No worries. I should've clarified. I'm following a step-by-step tutorial, and one of the steps actually exposed a **thanks** function within the **blog.py** controller. However, the tutorial occasionally misses steps and/or instructions, and I end up getting stuck. For instance, in their example there was no **thanks** view page either, but it still displayed the redirect successfully. So a lot of this stuff I'm figuring out on my own or via SO, google, etc. Stackoverflow is pretty awesome though. You guys bailed me out many times on variety of issues.

Answer (score 3):

So, after tweaking a number of things, and removing all of the compiled files, and starting from scratch again, the solution turned out to be way more simple than I was trying to make it.
I simply defined a function called **thanks** in the aforementioned **blog.py** controller, and returned the local variables, like so:

```
def thanks():
    return locals()
```

I then added a **blog/thanks** *view* file, with a basic html header, stating:

```
Thank you for submitting the form!
```

And it finally redirected the **display_form** blog page as intended to a **thanks** page, thereby flashing the *form accepted* message (also as expected).

Thanks for your help, Anthony!
Cheers.